# Measure Theory proof

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Give me a jump start for this

Prove that if $t_n \uparrow t$ then $(-\infty,t_n]\uparrow (- \infty,t)$ and $t_n<t$.

I understand the first part but how do I relate the first with the second

Comment: there should be - sign near second infinity

Comment: Do you want to prove that $\cup_{n\geq 0}(-\infty,t_n)=(-\infty,t)$?

Comment: I want to prove that if lim(t_n)=t then it is true that  (-∞,t_n]↑(- ∞,t)

Comment: U might be right

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in (-\infty,t)$ since $(-\infty,t)$ is an open set there is $t_n$ such that $x\in (-\infty, t_n)$, because $t_n\to t$, so $(-\infty,t)\subset \cup_{n\geq 0}(-\infty,t_n).$ Since $(-\infty,t_n)\subset (-\infty,t)$ for every $n$ we have that $\cup_n(-\infty,t_n)=(-\infty,t)$.